# How much torque does it take to turn a doorknob?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, torque

How much torque does it take to turn a doorknob?  I'm not looking for an exact answer, just a ballpark for someone who doesn't have a sense of everyday amounts of torque.

Here's a very ordinary picture of a very ordinary doorknob, the type I'm imagining for this question:

[image: an ordinary doorknob]

Comment: Is this a round or a handle doorknob?

Comment: @ja72, I'm not sure what distinction you're trying to draw, so I put up a picture of the most normal-looking doorknob I could find.  Hopefully it answers what you're asking.

Comment: with a round doorknob you rely on friction, vs. the handle doorknob you rely on a force at a distance.

Comment: In principle this kind of question is good for learning to ballpark figures, but the problem is devloping into argument and repetition.

Comment: @dmckee, How could this question be changed to make it a good ballpark question?  It seems to me that having a ballpark question for people who have no sense of everyday torques would be quite useful.

Comment: Joe, I don't really know how to make it fit the site better. This important skill is usually transmitted by example: you see professors and mentors and other students doing it over and over again until it seems natural. If you ever find your self doing at a cocktail party not primarily attended by scientists you will know that you have completed your transition to the nerd side and forever shall it dominate your destiny.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hanging my iPhone with case (0.16 kg), on a lever arm 12 cm from the center of the door knob just starts turning it. Therefore,

$$m\cdot g\cdot L = 0.19 \mathrm{\,Nm}.$$

Answer (score 2):

How about 5 inch-pounds max (0.56 Nm). It would take a weight of 1 pound hung at a distance of 5 inches to turn some doorknobs. Of course it really varies with the strength of the return spring, the friction and the amount of travel the latch needs.

Comment: 5 inch-pounds = 0.56 Nm

Comment: That sounds high.  I'm guessing less for most ordinary door knobs.  Imagine the outer diameter of the knob is 1.5 to 2 inches from the center, do you really think you exert more than 1 pound turning force at that radius?

Comment: Please, at least on this site, use units from the metric system, or at least state values in both systems. Looking at [this figure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_system#Usage_around_the_world) might make you realize how isolated the USA still is in this respect, especially in the context of the world wide web.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I said this is max. It is high but to make sure you can open a door you better be able to supply this torque.

Comment: @Rody: No, I'm going to use whatever I am comfortable with and convert as necessary to whatever I think is relevant at the time. Personally, I have a reasonable sense of what a pound is, but no such sense for a Newton without doing the conversion. The OP didn't specify units, so inch-pounds, foot-pounds, Newton-meters, or slug-fathom-furlongs per fortnight-squared are all valid.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: and yes, I'm going to make a stance against your statement "the OP didn't specify units, so I'll use [*whatever I darn well please*]" -- if the OP doesn't mention units, you should use the *default* system used in the sciences, which is *metric*; Physics SE site moderators [seem to agree with me here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15/shall-we-force-to-use-si). I'm making a big issue out of this, because if *you* don't put metric in everywhere, then *we* (the remaining 95.4% of the world's population, all using metric) have to clean up after you all the time.

Comment: @Rody: Of course I could have done the conversion, but I was expressing the value in the form easiest for me.  *You* convert if *you* want it in different units.  Also it was worth writing the comment because of your holier-than-though arrogant attitude.  Your "let me google that for you" link is rude and really uncalled for.

Answer (score 0):

There is so many different variables in play to really give any answer, how old is the door noob, was there a bit of paint in the door nob assembly from the last time it was painted, has the components worn out or have started to oxidize, just to many different variables that I want to be able to give you an answer.

Comment: This is why I'm asking for a ballpark number.  Is it 0.1 foot-pounds?  1 foot-pound?  10 foot-pounds?  100 foot-pounds?

Comment: OK, 1ft-pound, that be maybe a pefect door noob out of the packet.